# How to discourage contestants from entering a lottery twice?

Tags: statistics, game-theory, random, gambling

Suppose you have a lottery. And you want to prevent participants from buying multiple tickets. What would be the best way to discourage this?

For example, increasing the win-chance for all previously sold ticket-numbers as soon as a new one is bought, would make sure everyone buys only one, because buying more than one puts you at an even larger disadvantage compared to the existing ticket-holders.

But this is far from fool-proof, so is there a better way?

Comment: I have a question. What is the probability of a single ticket winning?

Comment: @Adam The probability should be equal for each participant, and 100% in total, so with 10 of them, the chance that you win should be 10%.

Comment: and with infinity tickets 0 percent?

Comment: @Adam I shouldnt have used the word 'infinite' I just ment that people could possibly get multiple tickets, for which Im trying to think of a solution, so I hoped the answers on this question could help me get in the right direction.

Comment: @Muis What's to prevent 1 participant by pretending that he's actually 2 participants and hence doubling his chance of winning? As such, for your question to make sense, the only chance is 0, and that's easy to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each player $P_i$, let $\sigma(P_i)=k_i$ be the number of tickets player $i$ bought.

Furthermore let  $(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sigma(P_i))^2 = H $ by the number of tickets given "to the house".

When the lottery is done, if a house ticket wins then every player loses.

In this scenario a player has no incentive to buy any tickets after the first.

For a players first ticket his chances of winning are $\frac{1}{H+\sqrt{H}}$

However his second ticket gives a probability of $\frac{2}{3\sqrt{H}+H+2}$.

With a bit of calculus it's easy to verify that their probability is no less than before buying the extra ticket. So they have no incentive to change, even if the ticket is free.

Comment: This is a smart solution if I understand it correctly; every time a player buys a ticket, the odds of any player winning decreases drastically, right? However, I wonder if there exists any solution to this problem that ensures that some player will win (not the house). If we cannot keep track of which players have bought more than one ticket, it seems to me that no solution can ensure this.

Comment: I think that having the lottery get played again if the house wins, and tweaking the exponent of the houses number of tickets might give interesting results. However, this involves Markov chains and likely a lot of probability I don't know. But in view of the fact that buying tickets reduce other players chances drastically, I don't think it would work.

Comment: @Chiruno In my case it would be no problem to repeat the lottery over and over again, untill the house looses, and a player wins.. The only requirement Im looking for is that it should not be possible for any player to gain an advantage over other players, and if I understanded your proposal correctly everybody has an equal chance of winning?

Comment: @Muis As my proposal stands, everyone has no incentive to buy more than one ticket, and so everyone has an equal chance of winning with their one ticket. However, I have not done much analysis on a repeated game when house loses, in which case it might be better to buy extra tickets. I should be able to construct a small example to test, I'll edit this comment with my results later.

Comment: @Muis No thanks, I'll solve it out of interest. Are the prizes divisible? If the prize is something like money then the repeated-games can be made to work by lowering the prize value after each House win and messing around with the number of House tickets generated.

Comment: @Chiruno Yes, the prizes are totally divisible. Also, the tickets are not required to be free. We only made them free to encourage people to get their first ticket, but I think it would be better to charge for a small fee for a ticket if thats possible.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the set of tickets is uncountable, only having a finite subset of tickets will almost surely have you lose.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely

In which case every person does have an equal chance of winning, with this chance being 0.

Comment: The set of tickets will be identitcal to the number of contestants in most cases, because there should be no advantage to anyone to get multiple tickets to increase their win-chance.

Comment: You could say that if no one will ever win, then chance is always 0.

Comment: Someone can indeed win, however the chance that they do is 0. There is a subtle but important difference between something being impossible and having probability 0. Also, the fact that there is no advantage to buying additional tickets follows from the fact that the chance a ticket wins is 0, not the other way around.

Comment: @Muis Rather than statistical, the question is much more Game theoretical. From the way you posed the question it seems possible to just sell the second ticket to whomever at exorbitant prices but you seem to be positing people buying tickets secretly, in which case you make no difference between a person buying their second tickets and a different person buying their first. And so any scheme that discourages buying a second ticket for one person would similarly discourage another person from their first.

Comment: @Chiruno But the lottery is just a metaphor for my real problem, where the lottery tickets are free. So why would it discourage another person from getting their first ticket? They'll have a free chance to win, so encouraging them to get the first ticket will be easy, the hard part is to prevent them from getting a second ticket.

Answer (score 1):

If we can keep track of how many tickets have been sold and who has purchased one, then we can charge a price for the second ticket that is always beyond the marginal value of that ticket.

Suppose $N$ tickets have been sold, the lottery is structured so that one ticket must win and each ticket has an equal chance of winning. If Alice wants to buy a second ticket we can charge her a price $P_2 > J \frac{1}{N + 1}$ where $P_2$ is the price of the second ticket and $J$ is the value of the jackpot. This means that Alice's expected value from purchasing the ticket is negative, so a rational self-interested agent would not purchase the second ticket.

Of course, using this reasoning, no one would ever buy a ticket to any of the major lotteries currently run by the state governments in the US. So, as a real-world solution this probably will not work.

Comment: Its not ment as a real-world lottery, I'm trying to solve a problem where I want to select 1 random target from a large pool. But its very easy for people to enter the pool multiple times, and increase their chance to become the selected target, so I need a scheme where you'd have the largest chance to win by entering only once. And in your solution I would still have to know wether it was her first ticket or not, else she ould have a negative expected value for the first one too.

Comment: @Muis Well, with this 'solution' you CAN increase your chance of winning by entering multiple times. It just isn't worth it.

Comment: But what do I charge for the first ticket? Because I can't differentiate if Alice already bought one or not?

Comment: @Muis You can charge whatever you like for the first ticket. As I said, I'm assuming here we can keep track of who has bought a ticket. Otherwise, this doesn't work because we don't know who to charge the 'entry' price and who to charge the 'prohibitive' price to

Comment: Unfortunately I cant keep track of who already bought a ticket or not.. If that was the case, why wouldn't I simply refuse to sell them a second one? :) I thought about decreasing the size of the jackpot with every ticket sold, so that someone only can increase your chance to win less, and the endresult will be the same for them? Would something like that be possible?